# one_hot Vs Tokenizer for Word representation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have seen in many blogs , people using one_hot (from tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot ) to convert the string of words into array of numbers which represent indices. This does not ensure unicity. Whereas Tokenizer class ensures unicity (tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer ).
Then why is one_hot prefered over tokenizer?

Update: I got to know that hashing is used in One_hot to convert words into numbers but didn't get its  importance as we can use the tokenizer class to do the same thing with more accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by uncity. I expect it has to do with the sequential relationship between the words. That of course is lost with ine hot encoding. However one-hot encoding is used when the number of words is limited. If say you have 10 words in the vocubulary you will create 10 new features which is fine for most neural networks to process. If you have other features in your data set beside the word sequences say numeric ordinal parameters you can still create a single input model.  However if you have 10,000 words in the vocabulary you would create 10,000 new features which at best will take a lot to process. So in the case of a large vocabularly it is best to use "dense" encoding" versus the sparse encoding generated by one hot encoding. You can use the results of the tokenizer encoding to serve as input to a keras embedding layer which will encode the words into an n dimensional space where N is a value you specify. If you have additional ordinal features then to process the data your model will need multiple inputs. Perhaps that is why some people prefer to one hot encode the words.

Comment: Actually , Both the classes return the array of same dimensions (which is the length of string )
Tokenizer first take vocabulary as input to process and then it returns the array of numbers (which represent the indices).
One_hot just works on the string and return the array of numbers (which also represent the indices) but we can have same number for 2 different words (does not ensure unicity).